# Thesaurus terms ignored when search is queried through REST

Tags: 2013, rest, enterprise-search

I have a SharePoint 2013 portal running enterprise search. I have imported some thesaurus with the `Import-SPEnterpriseSearchThesaurus` cmdlet. For example, let's say as a test I have associated the string "ABCD" with "opportunities." When I search for "ABCD" in the search center site collection, I get several results where the string "opportunities" is hit-highlighted, which is the expected behavior.

If I execute a search with javascript over the REST interface in the form `<myurl>/_api/search/query?querytext="ABCD"`, I get only results that match the actual string "ABCD," and nothing that contains "opportunities." It's as if the thesaurus terms were ignored when I execute the search over REST. I expect to get the same results that I get when I use the search center.

Is there anything I have to do to make this work? The REST interface is exposed anonymously, so I use a `QueryTemplatePropertiesURL` parameter, and I make the query over HTTP GET. For other searches (ones that do not rely on thesaurus terms), I get the same results back when I execute the query in REST vs. the web interface in the search center.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and the Thesaurus is not called if the synonym is not exactly the same. Therefore `ABCD` will turn into `Opportunities` but if the name is `Opportunities A`, it will not find it. You also cannot call `ABCD*` to get `Opportunities*` as `ABCD* != ABCD`.

I am trying to find a way to add a star after the thesaurus is called but nothing so far.

just be careful as the first line is ignored as the file reads that one as the Header